# $q.all aborts all promises when gets a 404 response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I have a set of promises that I want to be run simultaneously. I'm using `$q.all` in order to achieve that. When one promise returns a 404 response any other one are unfulfilled. I want to be able to get an error promise individually on $q.all function. How do I do this?

```
var idPais = 13, idUF = 20;
var promises = [
    PaisAPI.list(), 
    UnidadeFederativaAPI.list(idPais), 
    MunicipioAPI.list(idUF)
];

$q.all(promises).then(
    function(values) {
        var paises = values[0].data;
        var ufs = values[1].data;
        var municipios = values[2].data;

        console.log('paises ', paises.length);
        console.log('ufs ', ufs.length);
        console.log('municipios ', municipios.length);

        $scope.paises = paises;
        $scope.unidadesFederativas = ufs;
        $scope.municipios = municipios;
    },
    function(error) {
        if (error.status == 500) {
            alert('Server error');
        }
        //when one of the promises get a 404 response any other one are unfulfilled
    }
);
```

Comment: Make the individual promises not fail when you get a 404 error: add an error handling routine on each on that substitutes in the value you want to use when the server wasn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-factor the code to put the values on `$scope` before executing `$q.all`:

```
var idPais = 13, idUF = 20;
var promiseObj = {};

promiseObj.paises = PaisAPI.list()
  .then(function (response) {
    var paises = response.data;
    console.log('paises ', paises.length);
    $scope.paises = paises;
    return paises;
}).catch(angular.identity);

promiseObj.ufs = UnidadeFederativaAPI.list(idPais)
  .then(function (response) { 
    var ufs = response.data;
    console.log('ufs ', ufs.length);
    $scope.unidadesFederativas = ufs;
    return ufs;
}).catch(angular.identity);

promiseObj.municipos = MunicipioAPI.list(idUF)
  .then(function (response) {
    var municipios = response.data;
    console.log('municipios ', municipios.length);
    $scope.municipios = municipios;
    return municipios;
}).catch(angular.identity);
```

The `.catch(angular.identity);` **converts** a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise. Each API call executes in parallel.

Use `$q.all` to wait for all promises to complete either fulfilled or rejected:

```
$q.all(promiseObj).then(function (dataObj) {
     console.log("All API calls complete");
     if (dataObj.paises.status) {
         console.log("paises failed with ",dataObj.paises.status);
     };
     if (dataObj.ufs.status) {
         console.log("ufs failed with ",dataObj.ufs.status);
     };
     if (dataObj.municipos.status) {
         console.log("municipos failed with ",dataObj.municipos.status);
     };
});
```

One of the things that sets `$q.all` apart from other promise libraries is that AngularJS $q.all accepts an object hash of promises.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it is default behavior in accordance with Promises/A+ spec on which all this stuff is built upon.

[Documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for JS native promises states:

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. **It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.**

From angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for `all()`:

> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. **If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.**

All implementations across different frameworks should follow and actually follow this approach.

As a workaround, If your code returns 404 error after, lets say, an ajax call, try to resolve it too instead of rejecting. I mean treat this error as a positive outcome and resolve it with some special value like `false`, `{error: 404, message: 'Not Found'}` or `0` - to show difference for the client code later. Resolving instead of rejecting should make `all()` wait untill all the promises are done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that the errors which shouldn't make `$q.all()` fail are all handled by the individual promises. You should be sure to handle all of the error cases that you want to allow the `$q.all` to complete normally, but if there are other errors possible which should still abort the `$q.all` then those should be passed through using `$q.reject`. For example to return a length of -1 on an error 404:

```
function handle404(error) {
    if (error.status == 404) {
        return { data: { length: -1 }};
    }
    return $q.reject(error)
}
var promises = [
    PaisAPI.list().catch(handle404), 
    UnidadeFederativaAPI.list(idPais).catch(handle404), 
    MunicipioAPI.list(idUF).catch(handle404)
];
```

then the rest of the code as before. Or to just return an empty array in those cases:

```
function handle404(error) {
    if (error.status == 404) {
        return { data: []};
    }
    return $q.reject(error)
}
```

but that wouldn't be distinguishable from getting  back an empty array with no error.

Comment: You are returning a rejected promise. The `$q.all` will still abort on the first rejected promise. If you want to convert a rejected promise, `return` a value, not `$q.reject`.

Comment: @georgeawg, the OP wants 404 errors to not reject the promise. I assumed (possibly wrongly) that other errors such as 503 which are being handled in the `$q.all()` handler should still cause everything to abort. That's why `handle404` only handles 404 and passes other errors on.

Comment: @Duncan, I'm sorrry. My bad. It is not 503 error code, it is the 500 error code (server error).